# VSCode syntax highlighting for language I'm making isn't working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make a really simple language for a game I'm working on, and I want to implement syntax highlighting for it. I used the yo generator thing to make my extension for syntax highlighting, and put the folder in the Users.vscode\extensions directory, and restarted VSCode several times, but it isn't working. My language's file extension is "npc".

my npc.tmLanguage.json file is as follows

```json
    {
        "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
        "name": "NPC Programming Language",
        "patterns": [
            {
                "include": "#keywords"
            },
            {
                "include": "#strings"
            }
        ],
        "repository": {
            "keywords": {
                "patterns": [{
                    "name": "keyword.control.npc",
                    "match": "\\b(if|while|for|return)\\b"
                }]
            },
            "strings": {
                "name": "string.quoted.double.npc",
                "begin": "\"",
                "end": "\"",
                "patterns": [
                    {
                        "name": "constant.character.escape.npc",
                        "match": "\\\\"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "scopeName": "source.npc"
    }
```

and my language-configuration.json file is set up like

```json
    {
        "comments": {
            // symbol used for single line comment
            "lineComment": "//"
        },
        // symbols used as brackets
        "brackets": [
            ["{", "}"],
            ["[", "]"],
            ["(", ")"]
        ],
        // symbols that are auto closed when typing
        "autoClosingPairs": [
            ["<", ">"],
            ["{", "}"],
            ["[", "]"],
            ["(", ")"],
            ["'", "'"]
        ],
        // symbols that that can be used to surround a selection
        "surroundingPairs": [
            ["<", ">"],
            ["{", "}"],
            ["[", "]"],
            ["(", ")"],
            ["'", "'"]
        ]
    }
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, but no syntax highlighting comes up when I type things like "if" "return" "//", etc. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try F1 -> `Development: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` to open the token inspector in one of your npc files and see if your tokens are recognized. Using that you can fine tune your patterns.

Comment: @MikeLischke it just comes up with "No grammar or semantic tokens available," I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Sounds like your syntax definition has not been registered.

Comment: how would I go about resolving that?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom language extension last year that I knew worked. I recently reinstalled VS Code and ran into a similar loading issue.

First, let's check that your extension works: See if you can debug your extension. Open the project folder, press `F5`. It should open another VS Code window with your extension running. Open a file containing your language syntax and see if it highlights. If not, debug via `Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` as suggested in the previous comments.

If your language extensions seems to work, then try packaging the extension and installing it:

Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Open a terminal window (e.g. `cmd`) and type/run `npm install vsce`. This installed the `vsce` program local to my user profile (e.g Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\vsce`)

In that same terminal window, `cd` to your project folder.

Then run: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\vsce package`

Answer a few questions that come up, if any. (I said no to them, but you may have different answers.)

You should see a `.vsix` file get created. Now open VS code. Open the Extensions tab. Click `...` and select `Install from VSIX...`. Select the generated `.vsix` file and watch it install.

If for some reason the extension doesn't load/activate/enable, then restart VS Code and try to reinstall again (my install didn't seem the work the first time, but maybe that was because I did it in a debug VS code and didn't notice).